# split java dashed string

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string

```
str[] where str[0]="My-Name";
str[1]="is-drew";
```

I want to get a new string `str1[]` where `str1[0]="My"`, `str1[1]="Name"`, `str1[2]="is"` and `str[3]="drew"`. The code I tried to write has `split()` method and uses `String`'s but is too complicated and failed to run. Is there any easier way using for example `StringBuilder` or `Array`?

```
for(int i=0;i<result0.length;i++){
    temp=result0[i];
    temp1=temp.split("-");
    for(int y=0;y<temp1.length;y++){
        result1[y+z]=temp1[y];
        z=z+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't that complicated. Show us what you have done.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the scenario, a bit more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is it complicated !

```
String.split("-")
```

returns the string array.

Exactly what you needed

This will return what u needed.

```
public String[] splitMe(String[] arr){
    ArrayList<String> retList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String t:arr){
        String[] splits = t.split("-");
        for(String s: splits){
            retList.add(s);
        }
    }
    return retList.toArray(new String[retList.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you say `String.split(...)` is not working for you. You could do something like this:

```
String myString = "My-Name".split("-")[0];
String nameString = "My-Name".split("-")[1];
```

and it should work ok.

Answer (score 2):

`str[i].split("-");`
this will split the string `My-Name` as `My` and `Name`.

`List strList = new ArrayList();
// this part iterates
strList.addAll(Arrays.asList(str[i].split("-"));
strList.toArray(); // you have an array with all the split string.`

here you go.

Comment: That part is ok but then a want to add all these split-ed parts to a new string.I mean i have strings[] with 3 or 4 components and i want one by one add them to a new string[]

Comment: and then with strList.tostring() i can have the final string?

Comment: you need to say `Arrays.toString(strList.toArray());`

Answer (score 2):

You can do all the work with the split method. As an additional suggestion you can use a List:

```
final String[] str = new String[2];
str[0] = "My-Name";
str[1] = "is-drew";

final List<String> sum = new ArrayList<String>(4);
for (final String part : str) {
   sum.addAll(Arrays.asList(part.split("-")));
}
```